# App with google play servcice crashes while launch

Tags: android

All apps with google play service crash while launching in android mobile. I created an android apk file by running the android project and taking the apk file from bin folder. Am I not creating it correctly?

The crashes happens with the error:

> Unfortunately, app has stopped.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Running the project simply on eclipse creates the apk file,installs and starts it in the phone. From the error, I you have made programmatical error. Please provide logcat

Answer (score -1):

If you are using eclipse, riflght click the project, then export. That is how you build an apk

Comment: Running the project simply creates the apk file